# Classification metrics can't handle a mix of binary and unknown targets, how to ignore unknown targets and only consider integers?

Tags: python, compiler-errors, random-forest, prediction

I am solving a classification problem in which I am trying to predict the first column "gold" of my input file based on the values of the remaining columns in the same input file. My input file is under the form:

```
gold, callersAtLeast1T, CalleesAtLeast1T, ...

T,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

N,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

N,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

N,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

I am using probabilities to make predictions and I choose to refrain from making predictions in case my conditions are not satisfied. In other words, in case `if (probs[i][0]>=0.8) & (probs[i][1]<0.8):` or `(probs[i][0]<0.8) & (probs[i][1]>=0.8):` are not satisfied then I choose to leave `y_pred` equal to "None" and not assign to it "0" or "1". I receive the error `ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of binary and unknown targets` due to the line of code `print('confusion matrix\n',confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred))`. The reason for this is that `y_pred` contains both strings and integers, the content of `y_pred` is made of "0", "1" and "None". I would like to ignore all situations in which `y_pred` is equal to "None" and only perform the computation of `print('confusion matrix\n',confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred))` in case `y_pred` is equal to "1" or "0" and just skip all situations in which it is equal to "None" and ignore them. How to do that?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dataset = pd.read_csv( 'data1extended.txt', sep= ',') 
#convert T into 1 and N into 0
dataset['gold'] = dataset['gold'].astype('category').cat.codes

print(dataset.head())
row_count, column_count = dataset.shape
X = dataset.iloc[:, 1:column_count].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 0].values

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
# Feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

regressor = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=200, random_state=0)
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)

probs = regressor.predict_proba(X_test)

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix, accuracy_score
i=0
y_pred=[None]*len(y_test)
for i in range(len(probs)):
        #print('i==> ',i)
        if (probs[i][0]>=0.8) & (probs[i][1]<0.8):
               y_pred[i]=0

        elif (probs[i][0]<0.8) & (probs[i][1]>=0.8):
               y_pred[i]=1
        print(y_pred[i])
        print("Probabilities=%s, Predicted=%s" % (probs[i], y_pred[i]))
print(y_pred)
print('confusion matrix\n',confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred))
print('classification report\n', classification_report(y_test,y_pred))
print('accuracy score', accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
from sklearn import metrics

print('Mean Absolute Error:', metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_pred))
print('Mean Squared Error:', metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred))
print('Root Mean Squared Error:', np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)))
```